# How to access a python module variable using a string [ django ]

Tags: python, django, python-module

I have a django application, with a module called **"app"**
Now this module has a file called **"urls.py"** which has a variable called **"HOME_URL**"

What I'm trying to do ?

```
app_label = "app"
url = __import__(app_label).urls.HOME_URL
print url
```

That obviously doesn't work, but I hope you got what I'm trying to do, If not please comment I will edit the question to contain more info.

Comment: This works for me in the general case. What kind of error messages do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`import_module`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dadf2ee75f88653b94b9c05a3118fd1590853e77/django/utils/importlib.py#L26-L47) to load a module relative to the root of a django project.

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
app_label = "app"
url = import_module("%s.urls" % app_label).HOME_URL
```

This should work within your django project, or in `./manage.py shell`.

Comment: In Django 1.11, this results in an `ImportError: No module named importlib`; any idea where this helper has moved or whether it is still there?

Comment: Use the Python import_module if you're getting the import error @KurtPeek mentioned:

```from importlib import import_module```

Comment: In Django 1.11: from django.utils import module_loading

Answer (score 17):

If you're using Django 1.7+, you should use [`import_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.module_loading) instead.

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
app_label = "app"
url = import_string("%s.urls.HOME_URL" % app_label)
```

By the way, some clarifications about Python modules and packages.

A *package* is a folder containing files, including one file called `__init__.py`.  It sounds your 'app' 'module' is actually a package.

A *module* is a `.py` file within a package.  So your `urls.py` is actually a module.