# Referring to forms and models in views.py with variables

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When a user signs up on my site, they select a template that they'd like to see as part of the User Profile. In this case, because they want to see the 'green' profile, user.userprofile.color is equal to 1.

I've built a specific model (called model1) for the green template as well as a specific form (called form1) for that model. When the user selects 'green' in the UserProfile form and submits the form, an instance of the model1 is assigned to the user automatically

Within views.py, I'd like to create a generic view that takes the user.userprofile.color value and uses it to establish

a) what form to serve the webpage

b) what model the form is based on

Rather than hardcoding the form and model value like this:

def homepagetemplate(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form1(request.POST, request.FILES, 
    instance=request.user.model1)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/accounts/')        


else:
    form = form1(instance=request.user.model1)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', args)
```

Within the function rather than specifying 'form1' and 'model1', I'd like form and model values to equal to 'form'+i and 'model'+i where i equals the value of user.userprofile.color (i.e. 1).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: in template {% if user.userProfile.1 %} use template {% elif user.userProfile.2 %} use template {% endi f%}

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Django's contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

Basically you could create a model that will contain:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Templates(models.Model):
    template_name = models.SlugField()  # e.g. "green"
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # this will point to a template model
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # this one will point to a specific row in your DB - resulting with an model instance
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This model can be referenced by your users model by a `template = models.ForeignKey(Templates)` so that you'd have a possibility to do this:

```
template = User.objects.get(pk=1).template.content_object
```

Now for the form part... this will be more tricky. Maybe the `Templates` model could store an import path and then load that specific form with `import_modeule` [How to access a python module variable using a string [ django ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121983/how-to-access-a-python-module-variable-using-a-string-django)?

It feels like there maybe a more suited solution for your users needs. Even if the model would end up being a property bag and having a dynamic form [Jacob Kaplan-Moss one of Django's core contributors explain how to achieve the latter](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) for the former I couldn't find anything quick (and it would be to hard too much for this one question).